# Move View with image over the map

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a MapView (Google) and I want to add over the MapView another View which looks like a pin. This PinView should be moveable (using touch). My question is: how can I organize layouts for this purpose? And should I better use ImageView as PinView or custom View with onDraw method?